# How do I change first-party cookie settings in new versions of Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

On a previous version of Chrome I disabled all cookies by default, and used the little eye icon in the URL bar to re-enable them for just specific sites where I want to allow them.

That eye icon still works as usual, but in some recent upgrade (I'm running "114.0.5735.110 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)") the `Cookies` submenu under `Settings` -> `Privacy and Security` changed to `Third-party Cookies` and now seems to include only settings related to third-party cookies, with the settings for first-party cookies and the list of sites for which first-party cookies are enabled or disabled now missing.

Where do I now find the first-party cookie permissions (both default and the list of sites that are exceptions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now called "On-device site data" (which is why a search of settings for "Cookies" will not bring it up), most easily found by pasting `chrome://settings/content/siteData` into your URL bar.

You can also navigate from "Settings" via "Privacy and Security" to the "Site Settings" page. There, scroll down past "Recent Activity" and "Permissions" to the "Content" section, click on the "Additional content settings" at the end of that to expand the list, then scroll all the way to the bottom and click "On-device site data" to bring up the page with the URL above.

(Yes, this essentially down in the cellar, with a flashlight, at the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying "Beware of the Leopard." I have no idea where Google gets their UI designers. Probably the same place.)

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome 120, there is a new way to reach the mini menu that the eye icon used to access.

1. Click the "Tune" icon to the left of the address bar. It's a `○―` over a `―○`.
2. Click "Cookies and site data"
3. Click "Manage on-device site data"

This will bring up a new modal dialogue box containing the same information and options as the old eye icon mini-menu:

[image: On-device site data dialogue]

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the original question, which is why I'm leaving the other answer as the accepted one, but it does answer a slightly different question that's more important to me these days: "How do I get that dialogue box that had disappeared from the eye menu?" This makes life a lot more convenient again, so thanks a lot for this!

Comment: @cjs For sure! I'm not offended that yours remains accepted.